# How can i create the multiple lables and UIbutton continuously? like below layout

Tags: swift, uiview, uilabel, swift4, uiviewanimation

[image: create UILabel and UIButtons continuously without any UI issue]

I had a UI string like:(dynamically changed)

```
I need my new #@single,twin,triple@# zone nest smart thermostat installed for my #@gas combi,gas system,electric,LPG,oil@# #@description@# boiler which looks like this #@image@# #@location@# #@date@#

#@ - Buttons ->click change the single,twin,triple
#@description -> UITextarea
#@image  -> UImage view
```

How can i create all in single page like above mentioned image from the given String value

Comment: Your design seems a bit unusual. Are you sure you're designing an app for mobile and not trying to make an app be like a web page?

Comment: go and check the Bizzby app instruction page..

Comment: Ahh...I see what you mean. Though is that an image or a special character?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use liberary for that. Try this one [AttributedTextView](https://github.com/evermeer/AttributedTextView).